# $4^{th}$ Centered moment of exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Centered moment of order 4, for an exponential distribution $\mathcal{E}(\frac{1}{\theta})$

moment generating function

$\begin{array}{ll}
G_X(t)& =\mathbb{E}(\exp(t(X-\mu))\\
& = \mathbb{E}\{\exp(tX)\exp(-t\mu)\}\\ 
& = \mathbb{E}\{\exp(tX)\} \mathbb{E}\{\exp(-t\mu)\}\\
&= \exp(-tu) \mathbb{E}\{\exp(tX)\} 
\end{array}$

$ M_X(t)=\mathbb{E}\{\exp(tX)\} $,
and $\mu = \mathbb{E}(X)= \theta$

$M_X$ moment generating function   of an exponential distribution $ \mathcal{E}(\frac{1}{\theta})$

the $n^{th}$ moment is giving by $M^{(n)}(0)$

$\begin{array}{ll}
M(t)&=(1-\theta t)^{-1 }\\
M_X'(t)& = \theta (1-\theta)^{-2}\\
M_X''(t)& = -2 \theta^2 (1-\theta)^{-3}\\
M_X'''(t) & = 6 \theta^3(1-\theta t)^{-4}\\
M_X''''(t) & = 24 \theta^3(\theta(1-\theta t)^5)
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{ll}
  G_X''''(t)&=24 \theta^4((1-\theta t)^5) \exp(-tu) \\
  G_X''''(0)&=24 \theta^4
\end{array} $

is it correct?

Comment: The $4$th central moment is $\Bbb E\{(X-\mu)^4\}$; you've calculated $\Bbb E\{X^4\}$. But you can use $\Bbb E\{X^n\}=n!\theta^{-n}$ to compute$$\Bbb E\{(X-\mu)^4\}=\Bbb E\{X^4-4\mu X^3+6\mu^2X^2-4\mu^3X+\mu^4\}=\Bbb E\{X^4\}-4\mu\Bbb E\{X^3\}+6\mu^2\Bbb E\{X^2\}-3\mu^4.$$

Answer (score 1):

Without using the moment generating function, the 4th central moment for exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda=\frac{1}{\theta}$ is
$$\int_0^\infty\left(x-\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)^4\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx,$$
which evaluates to $\frac{9}{\lambda^4} = 9\theta^4$.